# Spring boot failing to start from command line with -jar option

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I tried to search through web and specifically stack overflow but I did not find solution. Apologies if I am asking this again.

I have spring boot app that connect to two database and do some record processing by reading from one db and writing to another db. Action is triggered by user by web interface. It is working fine when I run it through eclipse run as spring boot app. It even work when I run from command line using

```
mvn clean spring-boot:run
```

But somehow app is failing at start up when I run it through

```
java -jar target\myproject.war
```

Packaging is war in pom file.

Exact error message when using java -jar

```
Field targetRepo in <basepacakge>.repo.DbDao required a bean of type '<basepacakge>.repo.target.TargetRepo' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type '<basepacakge>.repo.target.TargetRepo' in your configuration.
```

To give my package and repo structure

Base Application is in basepacakge. Source repo is basepacakge.repo.src.SrcRepo and target repo is basepacakge.repo.target.TargetRepo.

Tried to compare log of both run from eclipse and java -jar there is nothing pointing to root cause. Any help how to debug it?

***Update: 1***

It is due to this setup. I have DbRepo class as @Component which is having attribute of srcRepo with @Autowired. SrcRepo class having @Repository annotation. Looks like in case of java -jar spring initializing DbRepo without first initializing srcRepo. Am I missing something obvious here?

***Update: 2***

pom.xml (Nothing special)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<groupId>*******</groupId>
<artifactId>*******</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>*******</name>
<description>*******</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    .......
</dependencies>

<scm>
    <developerConnection>*******</developerConnection>
</scm>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        ......
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        ........
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

***Update: 3***

This is the difference between working vs non working java -jar

Non working

```
@Component
public class DbDao {

@Autowired
 SrcRepo srcRepo;
}
```

Working

```
@Component
public class DbDao {

SrcRepo srcRepo;

public DbDao(SrcRepo srcRepo) {
    super();
    this.srcRepo = srcRepo;
}
}
```

Comment: java -jar for war file?

Comment: do you think it making difference? with packing type war, all file inside webapp automatically got added to war file if I use jar then I need to mention all resources location by myself in pom.xml. war seems to contain all needed config (main class) and library (tomcat etc).

Comment: Show your pom.xml.